# Attachment Action is disabled in SharePoint ribbon for List Item Add in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, office-365-developer

I am working in Office 365 sharepoint online site. recently i created a custom list. I tried to  create a new item for that list and wanted to upload a attachment also. For Iphone and Desktop Attachment action in Ribbon is enabled but for Ipad its disabled. [image] is this a normal behavior or we are missing any Tenant level setting. because this list does not have any customization.

Any quick response much appreciated.

Comment: Check with other lists whether they are also behaving this, if so then there might be issue with browser settings in iPad

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Yes all the other lists also behaves  the same in Ipad. Chrome Emulator and IPad actual device both place its disabled.

Comment: Now i have verified in my  dev tenant also, there also i see the same issue. is this a bug or restriction made by microsoft. but why it works in Iphone

Comment: Did you checked in developer tools console window, if you have any JavaScript errors then you might get some idea

Comment: @RaghavendraC Verified the console log, nothing is available either.